# the column name is not valid node name (if any) = , column name = d

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I spent hours trying to solve this error but I couldn't. I would be glad if someone could help me solve this.

Code:

```
FileStream fs;
fs = new FileStream(@imagename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] picbyte = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(picbyte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();
string query;
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\hotel.sdf");
conn.Open();
SqlParameter picparameter = new SqlParameter();
picparameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
picparameter.ParameterName = "pic";
picparameter.Value = picbyte;
query = "insert into Staffs(name, age, qualification, mobile, landline, salary, salary_type, address, work_type, reference, picture) values(" + textBox16.Text + ", " + textBox15.Text + "," + textBox14.Text + "," + textBox13.Text + "," + textBox12.Text + "," + textBox11.Text + "," + comboBox2.Text + "," + richTextBox2.Text + "," + textBox10.Text + "," + textBox9.Text + ", " + " @pic)";
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into Staffs(name, age, qualification, mobile, landline, salary, salary_type, address, work_type, reference, picture) values(" + textBox16.Text + ", " + textBox15.Text + "," + textBox14.Text + "," + textBox13.Text + "," + textBox12.Text + "," + textBox11.Text + "," + comboBox2.Text + "," + richTextBox2.Text + "," + textBox10.Text + "," + textBox9.Text + ", " + " @pic)", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Profile Added");
cmd.Dispose();
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
```

Error:

the column name is not valid node name (if any) = , column name = d

So far what I have found:

"column name = d" in the error is the value of the text field. If I type a in the text field the error changes to "column name = a".

If I put numbers in the text field instead of character the error changes to this
"A Parameter is missing [parameter ordinal = 1]. The datatype of the column is nvarchar.

I tried editing the database schema but nothing happened.

I checked for duplicate copies of the database and found none, so I suppose the problem is with the code.

The columns are in the datatypes nvarchar, int or image.

Just to be sure I checked the database to see if insert worked, the database is still empty.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You should also put your `FileStream`, `SqlCeConnection`, and `SqlCeCommand` into `using` blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use SQL parameters to avoid SQL injection issues.

But the reason your stuff is failing now is that you're not quoting your string values in the query. If you debug and look at the text of your command, you'll see something like `values(abc,def,ghi...)`, without the single-quotes around the strings.

That query tries to run, and of course it fails. SQL parameters eliminate the need for the single quotes, in addition to making your code safer and easier to read.

Comment: I changed the code to this  SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into Staffs('name', 'age', 'qualification', 'mobile', 'landline', 'salary', 'salary_type', 'address', 'work_type', 'reference', 'picture') values(" + textBox16.Text + ", " + textBox15.Text + "," + textBox14.Text + "," + textBox13.Text + "," + textBox12.Text + "," + textBox11.Text + "," + comboBox2.Text + "," + richTextBox2.Text + "," + textBox10.Text + "," + textBox9.Text + ", " + " @pic)", conn);  the error changed to this:

Comment: The values need to be quoted, not the column names.

Comment: I changed it to SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into Staffs(name, age, qualification, mobile, landline, salary, salary_type, address, work_type, reference, picture) values('" + textBox16.Text + "', '" + textBox15.Text + "','" + textBox14.Text + "','" + textBox13.Text + "','" + textBox12.Text + "','" + textBox11.Text + "','" + comboBox2.Text + "','" + richTextBox2.Text + "','" + textBox10.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "', " + " @pic)", conn);  I didn't quote the pic, another error is showing, please edit this code to the right one.

Comment: You'll have to work this one out on your own. Parameterize your SQL statement, name your textboxes something a little more sane, and you'll be able to track down the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter name is incorrect.  It should be `@pic`, not `pic`.

By the way, the way you're concatenating textbox values leaves you open to SQL Injection attacks.  Granted I don't know your context, but consider replacing the string concatenation with parameter value setting.

Comment: I tried inserting without pic column at all, but the error still comes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing the whole database and recreate it.

Obivously, this happens, if you have older version of table in database than you want to use, thus that column does not exist in that table.